# Conditionnal styles for cytoscape.js graph

Tags: javascript, graph, styles, conditional-statements, cytoscape.js

I want to change the style of my graph according to global Javascript variables. For exemple, assumung my edges got `name` and `price` attributes, I would like to make the labels of edges different, depending on a global `label_type` variable :

```
let lable_type = 'I_want_name_labels'
switch(lable_type) {
  case 'I_want_name_labels':
    cy.style().selector('edge').style({'label': 'data(name)'});
    break;
  case 'I_want_price_labels':
    cy.style().selector('edge').style({'label': 'data(price)'});
    break;
}
```

The above code does not do anything at all (no label displayed), I do not really understand why. 
My edges have the following structure :

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "node_node2",
    "source": "node1",
    "target": "node2",
    "directed": true,
    "name": "Baltazar",
    "price": 1095.73
  }
}
```

---

**Note** : I tried using `cy.filter('edge').style({'label': 'data(name)'})` instead, but then `data` does not seems accessible this way, I got this warning :

```
The style property `label: data(name)` is invalid
```

---

So, how to get conditionnal styling with cytoscape.js ? What am I missing here ?

Comment: Hi there, one quick question: Do you want to initialize nodes/edges with labels or do you want to change them afterwards?

Comment: So far I am not initializing edges with any labels, but I could do this with any data values, and change it afterwards

Comment: Why do you want to do that afterwards if it is much easier when doing that at initialization?

Comment: Well, I wanted to rework edges after applying style, but I realised it was smarter indeed to apply style after rework. And it is working fine, thanks for the leads !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the line you are looking for:

```
// .data() gets you all properties of the target element, .id() for example directly the id of the element
targetElement.style('label', targetElement.data('faveColor'));
```

Here is a working demo on how to initialize and then alter the nodes/edges label:

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        "label": "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "center",
        "text-halign": "center",
        "height": "60px",
        "width": "100px",
        "shape": "rectangle",
        "background-color": "data(faveColor)"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "curve-style": "bezier",
        "control-point-step-size": 40,
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "Top",
          faveColor: "#2763c4",
          wants: "id"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "yes",
          faveColor: "#37a32d",
          wants: "id"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "no",
          faveColor: "#2763c4",
          wants: "id"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "Third",
          faveColor: "#2763c4",
          wants: "color"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "Fourth",
          faveColor: "#56a9f7",
          wants: "color"
        }
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "Top",
          target: "yes"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "Top",
          target: "no"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "no",
          target: "Third"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "Third",
          target: "Fourth"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "Fourth",
          target: "Third"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  layout: {
    name: "dagre"
  }
}));

cy.bind('click', 'node, edge', function(event) {
  cy.nodes().each(function(ele, i, eles) {
    ele.style('label', (ele.data('wants') == 'id') ? ele.data('id') : ele.data('faveColor'));
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 85%;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.3.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js">
  </script>
  <!-- cyposcape dagre -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems fine, but how to do this for all edges (or nodes) at once ? That is the reason why I am using cy.filter and cy.selector so far

Comment: I added the filtering functionality for you, if you need help with that, just add another comment.